When does a property hold for infinite N if it holds for all finite N - Silva 2.3.5
In the proof that for a compact set F and open set G,

Silva asserts that if a property holds for all finite N, it must hold for infinite N:

When are you allowed to do this, and how do you rigorously justify this? Obviously it isn't true for any general property (e.g., V is isomorphic to its dual V* for every finite dimensional V, but not infinite)
What precisely characterizes the properties where if P(x) holds for any finite x, it holds for infinite x?

It's just the limit preserving the inequality.

To elaborate, there is no "$P(\infty)$" here - the infinite sum notation is shorthand for a limit. You should check that the limit preserves the inequality.

But is there any general statement we can make about logical formulas that are true for all finite inputs?

I don't think so, because what's the general way to translate a unary formula that makes sense on natural numbers into an infinite version of the statement? We aren't just "plugging in infinity" - in your example, a domain-specific limit operation was inserted.

But the question reminds me of the compactness theorem.

This follows from the following result. If you have a convergent sequence of real numbers $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with limit $a$ which is bounded above by some real number $M$, then $a\leq M$. Applying this to your case, you have that as $\lambda^{*}(G)$ is an upper bound for $\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{N} \lambda^{*}(I_{j}) + \lambda^{*}(F) : N\in\mathbb{N} \right\}$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda^{*}(I_{j}) + \lambda^{*}(F) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{N} \lambda^{*}(I_{j}) + \lambda^{*}(F) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{N} \lambda^{*}(I_{j}) + \lambda^{*}(F) \right) \leq \lambda^{*}(G).$$
Regarding your other question, the property you are looking at depends heavily on convergence in the real numbers. For example, if you take an increasing sequence of bounded subsets of the real numbers, it doesn't follow that their union is bounded, whereas if you instead had an increasing union of connected subsets, then it would hold that the union is connected. These statements typically reply heavily on specific properties and it is very difficult to make a general statement about relating something holding for a sequence of objects to it holding for some objected obtained in some kind of limiting process.
